# How do i move all lines from curser and below up one

Tags: normal-mode

Instead of pressing backspace multiple times to move lines up one, is there a vim shortcut/command that can do this?

I know you can move a single line up or down with `:m -` or `+`, so I figure it there should be a command for this aswell but can't find the documentation for it.

Just figured out you can press `dd` on the blank line to move everything up.

Comment: To move all the lines, from the current one down to the last one, one line upward, you could also use a range: `:.,$m-2`

Comment: also, `kddGp` should do the same thing as `:.,$m-2`...

Comment: I'm confused; do you want to move a set of lines *to* a specific place in the document, preserving existing lines by shifting or swapping them? Or do you want to move lines and delete intervening or replacing lines? Can you provide a concrete example of your task?